# Chop function is not working in PHP

Tags: php, string

This is my php code:

```
$artstruct=$author.' ('.$year.'). '.$title.'. '.$journal.', '.$volume.'('.$number.'), '.$pages;
if(strpos($artstruct,"}")){
    $art= chop($artstruct,"}");
    echo $art;
}
else{ 
    echo $artstruct;
}
```

The value of `$artstruct` before `if(strpos($artstruct,"}"))` is this

> Ames, S. C., Tan, W. W., Ames, G. E., Stone, R. L., Rizzo Jr, T. D., ... Rummans, T. A. (2011). A pilot investigation of a multidisciplinary} quality of life intervention for men with biochemical recurrence of prostate cancer. Psychoâ€oncology, 20(4), 435-440

`chop` function doesn't remove `}` from the above string. However if I change the value of `$artstruct` like below

```
$artstruct="This is a string with { and }"
if(strpos($artstruct,"}")){
    $art= chop($artstruct,"}");
    echo $art;
}
else{ 
    echo $artstruct;
}
```

`chop` function actually removes `}` from `$artstruct`. I don't know why `chop` is not functioning in the first php code even though `$artstruct` has `}` in both examples.

Comment: What's the value of `$artstruct` in the first code?

Comment: output of $artstruct when echoing it:  Ames, S. C., Tan, W. W., Ames, G. E., Stone, R. L., Rizzo Jr, T. D., ... Rummans, T. A. (2011). A pilot investigation of a multidisciplinary} quality of life intervention for men with biochemical recurrence of prostate cancer. Psychoâ€oncology, 20(4), 435-440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php, `chop` is an alias of http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

Since the value of `$artstruct` in the first code is the following

> Ames, S. C., Tan, W. W., Ames, G. E., Stone, R. L., Rizzo Jr, T. D., ... Rummans, T. A. (2011). A pilot investigation of a multidisciplinary} quality of life intervention for men with biochemical recurrence of prostate cancer. Psychoâ€oncology, 20(4), 435-440

The position of `}` is not at the last character, so `chop($artstruct,"}")` doesn't do anything to `$artstruct`.

If you want to replace all occurences of `}` from `$artstruct`, you should use [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead

```
$art = str_replace("}", "", $artstruct)
```

You should also change

```
if(strpos($artstruct,"}"))
```

to

```
if (strpos($artstruct,"}") !== false)
```

in case `$artstruct` has `}` at the first position.

Comment: ya, chop only removes the end of the string. Thanks for the explanation and an answer.

Comment: the string `}` was in the middle thats why trim wasn't affecting it. anyways +1